# "Access Denied user root error code 1045 (28000)" after changing root passwords

Tags: command-line, mariadb, mysql-connection

I'm encountering an "Access Denied user root error code 1045 (28000)" error with user root. I'm facing this problem after changing passwords. It was working fine before, and I'm confused about where I might be making a mistake.

I changed the password for root on localhost, but it's not working in one specific condition. The server starts working only when I use the following commands:

```
systemctl stop mysql
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql /var/run/mysqld
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

After that, I just type `mysql -u root` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the server starts working. However, when I close Putty, it stops working, and I encounter the error "1045 (28000)" again.

Comment: I have tried to correct the formatting etc. of [your original question text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/756488/1). I'm not certain I have been able to capture all the nuances, so please edit it if there is anything wrong.